Stubbing Firestore with Sinon does not work
I'm trying to stub a specific Firestore Document Reference which I want to get with the Firestore get Function with Sinon. Unfortunately I'm not able to make it work. The Function which should call the stub seems to call always the original Firestore get Function and not the stub.
My Setup is a Firebase NodeJS project with Mocha as Testing Framework and a Firebase Emulator which I use in the Tests.
The Testing against the Firebase Emulator works fine but I also want to Test the cases when for example a Firestore get Function returns an error. For those cases I'm trying to use Sinon. This is my Test:
import { expect } from "chai";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import { admin } from "../firebaseConfig";
import * as myFunctions from "../promoter";
import { test } from "./testSetup";

after(async () => {
    test.cleanup();
});

describe("Promoter Functions Tests", () => {

    afterEach(async () => {
        try {
            await test.firestore
                .clearFirestoreData({ projectId: "finanzwegbegleiter" });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error clearing Firestore data:", error);
        } finally {
            test.cleanup();
        }
    });

    describe("createPromoter Tests", () => {
        const usersPath = "users";
        const landingPagesPath = "landingPages";

        const parentUserID = "2";
        const landingPageIDs = ["3", "4"];

        beforeEach(async () => {
            // Set up Firestore with necessary documents
            await admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(parentUserID).set({
                email: "test@test.de"
            });
            for (const id of landingPageIDs) {
                await admin.firestore().collection("landingPages").doc(id).set({
                associatedUsersIDs: [],
            });
        }
    });

    describe("test", () => {
        let sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox;
        let docStub: sinon.SinonStub;

        beforeEach(async () => {
            sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

            docStub = sandbox.stub(admin.firestore().collection(landingPagesPath).doc("3"), 'get');
        });

        it("should fail if fetching landingpage failed", async () => {
            const error = new Error('Failed to fetch landing page');
            docStub.rejects(error);
            // Prepare Firestore mock data
            await admin.firestore().collection(usersPath).doc(parentUserID).set({
                email: "test@test.de",
            });

            const landingPageIDs = ['3', '4'];
            const promoterID = "1";

            const wrapped = test.wrap(myFunctions.createPromoter);
            const data = {
                id: promoterID,
                parentUserID: parentUserID,
                email: 'test@example.com',
                code: '123456',
                landingPageIDs: landingPageIDs,
            };

            const context = { auth: { uid: parentUserID } };

            try {
                await wrapped(data, context);
                expect.fail('Expected an error but got success');
            } catch (error: any) {
                console.log('THE ERROR', error);
                expect(error).to.be.instanceOf(functions.https.HttpsError);
                expect(error.code).to.equal('aborted');
                expect(error.message).to.equal('failed fetching landing page');
            } finally {
                // expect(getStub.called).to.be.true;
                sandbox.restore();
            }
        });
    });
});
});

This is the Function that I would like to test:
export const createPromoter = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const promotersPath = "unregisteredPromoters";
  const usersPath = "users";
  const landingPagesPath = "landingPages";

  const unregisteredPromoterModel = constructUnregisteredPromoterModel(data);

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "***",
    port: 587,
    auth: {
      user: "***",
      pass: "***",
    },
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: "***",
    to: [
      "***",
      data.email,
    ],
    subject: "***",
    html: "***" + data.code,
  };

  if (!context.auth) {
    return {status: "error", code: 401, message: "not signed in"};
  }

  await admin.firestore().collection(promotersPath)
    .doc(unregisteredPromoterModel.id).set(unregisteredPromoterModel)
    .catch((error) => {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "aborted",
        "Creating the promoter document failed",
        error
      );
    });

  // Get all landing pages references with the specific ids
  // and save the promoter id in the associatedUsers
  await Promise.all((unregisteredPromoterModel
    .landingPageIDs ?? []).map(async (id: string) => {
    const landingPageRef = admin.firestore()
      .collection(landingPagesPath).doc(id);
    const landingPage = await landingPageRef.get().catch((error) => {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "aborted",
        "failed fetching landing page",
        error
      );
    });
    if (!landingPage.exists) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "aborted",
        "The landingpage does not exist"
      );
    }
    await landingPageRef.set({
      "associatedUsersIDs":
          admin.firestore.FieldValue
            .arrayUnion(unregisteredPromoterModel.id),
    }, {merge: true}).catch((error) => {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "aborted",
        "failed saving promoter ids in associated users of the landingpage",
        error
      );
    });
  }));
  // save promoter id in parent user
  const parentUserRef = admin.firestore().collection(usersPath)
    .doc(data.parentUserID);
  const parentUserSnapshot = await parentUserRef.get().catch((error) => {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "aborted",
      "Fetching parent user failed",
      error
    );
  });
  if (!parentUserSnapshot.exists) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "aborted",
      "parent user does not exist"
    );
  }
  await parentUserRef.set({
    "unregisteredPromoterIDs":
      admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(unregisteredPromoterModel.id),
  }, {merge: true}).catch((error) => {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "aborted",
      "Saving promoter id in parent user failed",
      error
    );
  });
  await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions).catch((error) => {
    console.log("E-Mail failure: " + error.toString());
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "aborted",
      "Sending email with registration code failed",
      error
    );
  });
  return {
    success: true, response: "successful created document",
  };
});


especially this part of the function:
const landingPageRef = admin.firestore()
        .collection(landingPagesPath).doc(id);
const landingPage = await landingPageRef.get().catch((error) => {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
          "aborted",
          "failed fetching landing page",
          error
        );
      });


When I run the Tests, this is the message I get:
THE ERROR AssertionError: Expected an error but got success

Promoter Functions Tests
createPromoter Tests
test
should fail if fetching landingpage failed:
AssertionError: expected AssertionError: Expected an error but got… { …(3) } to be an instance of HttpsError

I would expect that the stubbing works like this and that the const landingPage = await landingPageRef.get() should fail.
This is the firebaseConfig.ts that I import:
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    projectId: "***",
    storageBucket: "***.appspot.com",
  });

  const db = admin.firestore();

  if (process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST) {
    db.settings({
      host: process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST,
      ssl: false,
      ignoreUndefinedProperties: true,
    });
  } else {
    db.settings({ignoreUndefinedProperties: true});
  }
}

export {admin};

And this is the testSetup that I import:
import * as functionsTest from "firebase-functions-test";

process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT = "***";
process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST = "127.0.0.1:8080";
process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST = "http://127.0.0.1:9199";
process.env.STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST = "http://127.0.0.1:9199";
process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST = "127.0.0.1:9099";
process.env.AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST = "127.0.0.1:9099";

const test = functionsTest.default({
    projectId: "***",
    storageBucket: "***.appspot.com",
});

export { test };

does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? I am thankful for every hint.
